# Is there a possibility in IntelliJ (or other free IDE/Tool) to indent whole project (only indentation without formatting))

Tags: java, format, indentation

I want to format code in my project. First of all I want to make consistent indentation in all the java files.

I know there is `CTRL+ALT+L` option, but it also formats other things - spacing in braces and so on.

`CTRL+ALT+I` is what I want to do, but automatically on all classes in project.

I checked Eclipse plugin, JIndent tool and none of those tool meet the requirements.

What do I expect is having all java files in a consistent indentation style (2 spaces) and all other aspects of formatting not changed.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Google Java code formatter which brings uniformity in both Eclipse and Intellij Idea IDE. I provide below the link.

https://github.com/google/google-java-format

You can install the plugin in eclipse and make changes in Eclipse Preference page. In case of **Eclipse**, you have to use the key command as **CTRL+SHIFT+F**

In case of **Intellij IDE**, you have to use the key command as **CTRL+ALT+L** to format the code.

You can see the screen shot for Eclipse preference Page below.
[image]

You can see the screen shot for Intellij Idea setting page below.
[image]

Comment: I have already tried this. In does not meet requirements, because it not only indents the files. For example it also do the following:
`
`public void method(){ }`
into

`public void method() { } `

Comment: If you want to do at the project level, you can also do it in eclipse by making right click and select source > format.

Comment: In case of Intellij IDE, you can right click and select ReFormat code.

Comment: I would suggest change tab to spaces, it will indent properly.